# Jenkinsfile: "RejectedAccessException: No such field found" in catch block

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to add the input status feature to my Jenkins stage code.
But it is throwing :

> org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException:
>   No such field found:

I tried to write this block as

```
catch (org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException e) {
    cause = e.causes.get(0)
    echo "Aborted by " + cause.getUser().toString()
    if (cause.getUser().toString() != 'SYSTEM') {
    startMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
    userAborted = true
    } else {
      endMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
    if (endMillis - startMillis >= timeoutMillis) {
          echo "Approval timed out. Aborting the deployment."
      userAborted = true
    } else {
          echo "SYSTEM aborted, but looks like timeout period didn't complete. Aborting."
          userAborted = true
        }
    }
  }
```

but with this code when i was aborting the job it was getting stuck.

so i modified with the below code :-

```
catch (Exception e) {
    cause = e.causes.get(0)
    echo "Aborted by " + cause.getUser().toString()
    if (cause.getUser().toString() != 'SYSTEM') {
    startMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
    userAborted = true
    } else {
      endMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
    if (endMillis - startMillis >= timeoutMillis) {
          echo "Approval timed out. Aborting the deployment."
      userAborted = true
    } else {
          echo "SYSTEM aborted, but looks like timeout period didn't complete. Aborting."
          userAborted = true
        }
    }
  }
```

Now the job is not getting stuck when aborted but throws this error again when the job is failed:

> org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException:
>   No such field found:

Comment: Can you post complete pipeline so we can try to reproduce?

Answer (score 1):

After checking the API of `RejectedAccessException` (found [here](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/script-security/org/jenkinsci/plugins/scriptsecurity/sandbox/RejectedAccessException.html)) I think the issue is `e.causes.get(0)`.

`causes` is not a field of `RejectedAccessException` like the exception is telling you so you can't access it obviously.

The API offers the method `getCause()` from `java.lang.Throwable` which can be used:

```
cause = e.getCause()
```

Btw `getUser()` is also not a method of the exception and will throw the same exception.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.. but in my case it was working.. I found the issue .. it was with the code where i was using a loop.so when there was any failure for that loop.. it was not able to catch the exception